# Finished enlighten progressbar is still on the screen

Tags: python, progress-bar

I've done an implementation with multiple counters using enlighten progress bar package in python.

***Problem:***
In the following program, `'A - first bar'` is still on the screen while `'B - first bar'` is counting up.

***Requirement:***
Once `run_first_loop` is finished execution, I want the progress bars to be removed from the screen.  Thus finally, while `'B - first bar'` is counting up, there should not be any other progress bars.

Thanks in advance!

```
import time
import enlighten


def run_first_loop(manager):
    ticks = manager.counter(total=100, desc='A - first bar', unit='ticks', leave=False)
    tocks = manager.counter(total=20, desc='A - second bar', unit='tocks', leave=False)

    for num in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work
        print(num)
        ticks.update()
        if not num % 5:
            tocks.update()
    ticks.close()
    tocks.close()


def run_sec_loop(manager):
    new_ticks = manager.counter(total=100, desc='B - first bar', unit='ticks', leave=False)

    for num in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work
        print(num)
        new_ticks.update()
    new_ticks.close()


manager = enlighten.get_manager()

run_first_loop(manager)
time.sleep(2) # I'm expecting "A-first bar" should be removed from the screen. But, it's not.
run_sec_loop(manager) # at this point, the previous bar is also there on the screen, which is a little annoying.
manager.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `clear=True` to `.close()` method to clear the bar upon closing:

```py
import time
import enlighten


def run_first_loop(manager):
    ticks = manager.counter(total=100, desc="A - first bar", unit="ticks", leave=False)
    tocks = manager.counter(total=20, desc="A - second bar", unit="tocks", leave=False)

    for num in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work
        print(num)
        ticks.update()
        if not num % 5:
            tocks.update()

    ticks.close(clear=True)  # <-- put clear=True here
    tocks.close(clear=True)  # <-- put clear=True here


def run_sec_loop(manager):
    new_ticks = manager.counter(
        total=100, desc="B - first bar", unit="ticks", leave=False
    )

    for num in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work
        print(num)
        new_ticks.update()
    new_ticks.close()


manager = enlighten.get_manager()

run_first_loop(manager)
time.sleep(
    2
)  # I'm expecting "A-first bar" should be removed from the screen. But, it's not.
run_sec_loop(
    manager
)  # at this point, the previous bar is also there on the screen, which is a little annoying.
manager.stop()
```